# write text on top of loaded box image right in the middle

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I created a box in paint and loaded it onto sprite using

```
     [Embed(source="Colbox.png")]
     var Colbox:Class;
     private var NBVar:Bitmap = new Colbox ();
```

Code.The code that sets the coordinates

```
        txtFld.x = 100;
        txtFld.y = 100;
        txtFld.width = 300;
        txtFld.height = 300;
        txtFld.text = "80";

        NBVar.x = 80;
        NBVar.y = 80;

        addChild(NBVar);
        addChild(txtFld);
```

However the number 80 does not appear in the middle of the colored box. Is there a easier method to achieve this with better accuracy ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NBVar.x = (colored_box.width/2) - (NBVar.width/2);
NBVar.y = (colored_box.height/2) - (NBVar.height/2);
```

This code will give u the perfect centre, and the `NBVar` should be the child of `colored_box`.